# NFC Tag Sticker showing Empty NFC Tag on Android with ICS installed

Tags: android, nfc

This is my first ever post in stack over flow . I have been stuck in a problem of reading NFC sticker Tag via Google Nexus S ICS android phone . Whenever I read the tag it shows a message "Empty NFC Tag" . Can anyone please help me in this regard ? I want to read the UID of NFC Sticker . 
http://www.buynfctags.com/nfc-tags/inlays/smartrac-circus-ntag-paper-nfc-tag.html
I have bought these tags . But I am unable to read its UID. Please help me because i need to continue with my project .

Thank you .

Comment: So which of the reader apps on Google Play did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
    void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
      ...
      String uid = toHex(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID));
      Toast.makeText(this, uid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ...
    }
```

(toHex is a convenience function that converts byte array to string)

Now, if your problem is that the tags lack a UID to begin with, then this probably won't help.  Perhaps you should order some tags that are pre-formatted and ready to write/read to.

Hope this helps,

Bp

Comment: Sorry for my late response . Actually I have been able to read UID as Blisterpeanuts mentioned but actually there were no NDEF message inside those tags as they were "Fresh" tags and not formatted ones.  Finally I found that I was missing NFCA . I was using MifareClassic in past and I hard coded that in my code for intent filter . Once I used NFCA it solved my problem because NTag is NFCA compatible . :)